# Slow boot time on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: boot, hard-drive, 19.10

I have dual boot system. The laptop is Dell G3.

1. Ram:8GB
2. Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz × 8
3. Graphics: Nvidia GTX 1050 4GB
4. Storage: 128 SSD + 1TB HDD.

I have windows installed on SSD. The disk details of HDD are follows: 
1. Partition 3 has root, 
2. Partition 4 has home, 
3. Partition 5 has swap

[image: HDD Details]

Partition 3 has root, Partition 4 has home, Partition 5 has swap

I've run systemd-analyze blame and systemd-analyze critical-chain and this is what I got:

```
systemd-analyze blame
 30.087s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 23.801s dev-sda3.device
 15.536s systemd-journal-flush.service
 15.423s snapd.service
 14.678s networkd-dispatcher.service
 13.889s gpu-manager.service
 13.618s dev-loop8.device
 13.365s udisks2.service
 13.087s ModemManager.service
 11.897s dev-loop11.device
 11.577s dev-loop22.device
 11.099s dev-loop0.device
 11.086s dev-loop18.device
 10.733s dev-loop6.device
 10.655s dev-loop17.device
 10.626s dev-loop23.device
 10.578s dev-loop9.device
 10.458s dev-loop14.device
 10.347s dev-loop20.device
  9.928s dev-loop10.device
  9.723s dev-loop4.device
  9.626s accounts-daemon.service
  9.319s dev-loop16.device
  9.235s dev-loop13.device
  9.047s dev-loop24.device
  8.983s dev-loop3.device
  8.884s NetworkManager.service
  8.869s dev-loop25.device
  8.779s dev-loop15.device
  8.758s grub-common.service
  8.708s apport.service
  8.403s dev-loop2.device
  8.177s dev-loop21.device
  7.571s systemd-udevd.service
  7.507s avahi-daemon.service
  7.470s thermald.service
  7.461s rsyslog.service
  7.459s bluetooth.service
  7.395s alsa-restore.service
  7.381s systemd-logind.service
  7.200s pppd-dns.service
  7.115s wpa_supplicant.service
  7.038s lm-sensors.service
  6.801s dev-loop7.device
  6.497s dev-loop1.device
  6.405s dev-loop19.device
  6.226s plymouth-read-write.service
  5.865s dev-loop12.device
  5.624s dev-loop5.device
  3.996s snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2d3\x2dstable-6.mount
  3.777s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-100.mount
  3.746s apparmor.service
```

For Critical Chain

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 16.342s
└─multi-user.target @1min 16.342s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @52.761s +261ms
    └─snapd.service @37.333s +15.423s
      └─basic.target @36.296s
        └─sockets.target @36.296s
          └─snapd.socket @36.275s +20ms
            └─sysinit.target @36.027s
              └─haveged.service @33.560s
                └─apparmor.service @29.802s +3.746s
                  └─local-fs.target @29.784s
                    └─home.mount @29.684s +99ms
                      └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-197da7c9\x2d3877\x2d4ac3\x2da5f4\x2d6853737eacc1.service @28.665s +992ms
                        └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-197da7c9\x2d3877\x2d4ac3\x2da5f4\x2d6853737eacc1.device @28.664s
```

Any idea what is causing my system to take lot of time to boot? I had similar issues on Ubuntu 19.04. I upgraded my system to 19.10. It did not make any difference.

Comment: Ubuntu is on the HDD, so it boots slowly, which is not unexpected.

Comment: 1) I see 17 Snaps (dev-loopnn.device) loading before you get to the Desktop. 2) Would you mind, please, removing the screenshots of GNOME Disk Manager and replacing them with the results of running `sudo gparted -l` from an Ubuntu terminal?  Click [edit] so you can edit your original question.  Also, a dedicated swap partition has been passe since 2017; when you install Ubuntu 19.10, by default it will create a swap file which performs as fast as a dedicated swap partition but is far easier to manage.